# Placing Random String values into an int Array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop

I am pretty newish at c++ and was wondering how I can place values randomly into an int array.What I want to do is use this function to place into a grid randomly for the purpose of creating a memory matching game.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define NOMINMAX
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void shuffleL(int [][8]);

int main()
{
                //shuffles characters
            shuffleS(charactersS);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
                {
                        cout << "---";
                }
                cout << endl;

                //output grid
                for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++)
                {
                    cout << r + 1 << " | ";
                    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
                    {
                        cout << " [VGC] ";
                        status[r][c] = false;
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
                cout << endl;
}

void shuffleL(int characters[][8])
{
      string vgc[50] = { "PacMan", "Laura", "Mario", "Sonic", "Link", "Snake", "Drake",  "Samus", "MegaMan", "Kratos",
    "Isaac", "DK", "Dante", "Crash", "Spyro", "Kirby", "Ryu", "Yoshi", "Sora", "Strider",
    "DigDug", "Lil_Mac", "Pit", "Booker", "Rayman", "Frogger", "Marcus", "Shepard", "Sly", "Ezio",
    "Guybrush", "Leon", "Raz", "Ninten", "Ralph", "Crono", "MaxPayne", "Fox", "Simon", "Cole",
    "Pheonix", "Corvo", "Parappa", "Faith", "Lucas", "Scorpion", "Gordon", "Roland", "Chell", "Olimar" };

  string temp;
  for (int s = 0; s <= 4; s++)
  {
      for (int x = 0; x<16; x++)
      {
          srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
          int i = rand() % 15 + 1;
          temp = vgc[x];
          vgc[x] = vgc[i];
          vgc[i] = temp;
      }
  }
  int i = 0;
  //Input of Values in Here
  for (int r = 0; r < 50; r++)
  {
    for (int c = 0; c < 50; c++)
    {
        characters[r][c] = vgc[i]; //THIS VGC GIVES ME THE ERROR
        cout << characters[r][c];
        i = i + 1;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

It also gives me an error for one of the variableNames (vgc) saying

1   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "int" exist

I am completely stumped on how to fix this solution.

Comment: how do you expect to store string in a container of type int?

Comment: Use string array instead.

Comment: [OT]:You should use `srand` only once. `std::shuffle` may also help.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what I am supposed to do to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont do  `int characters [] [8];` , but  `string characters [] [8];` . The type you specify at the start of the array declaration is the type of info the array will store.
Peace.

Comment: i did this, but then i received this error                                Error 3 error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl shuffleL(int (* const)[8])" (? shuffleL@@YAXQAY07H@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: Function declaration is int [] [8] when it should be string example-name-for-the-compiler-to-know-what-to-look-for [] [8]

Comment: Thank Very Much!! I got it to work. One last thing, (did i mention thank you?), I want the grid to output the same string twice. Like for example,first row would have a random generated string of: "Laura", "Ghost", "Drake", "Rob", "Rob". And the second row having randomly generated: "Drake", "Nathan", "Laura", "Ghost"

Comment: @JRoustider I think I understand but Im not sure... So lets say you get 2,3,1,4. You would like to randomize that array or randomly create a new one?

Comment: Well, with this program, I am trying to make a puzzle matching game. I already have the whole thing down, except the randomizing of the values behind the "cards". In the code above, I have the board/grid outputted in a multidimensional array with a face term of [vgc], and the function to randomize the strings (thanks for that btw). But now I just need to randomize two of each string and input the values into the board/grid so that the player can find two of each string and get a "match". Hope this clarified it.

Comment: So you want to get 2 members out of that array... Let me think about it. I'll post the code I would use when Im finished.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are trying to store *string* in your *int* type array.

```
for (int c = 0; c < 50; c++)
{
    characters[r][c] = vgc[i];  //<- **Here**
    cout << characters[r][c];
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: So how should I fix this?